# Sierpinski triangle html canvas Implementation

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, fractals

I wrote my [Sierpinski Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) fractal animation using HTML canvas with JavaScript: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2x4wzb5c/)

What do you think about it? How I can optimize it, if you see a need for that?

Code:

```
requestAnimationFrame(update);
    
const canvas = document.getElementById("c");
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var iterations = 0; //how many iterations to perform in current frame, count of fractal func invokes grows exponentially and can be calculated from sum: E 3^k, k = 0 to iterations
const maxIterations = 8; //used when animating, it's better to set 'gradientAnimation' to false, when setting 'maxIterations' to bigger values 
const center = { x: canvas.width * 0.5, y: canvas.height * 0.5 };
const halfTriangleSide = 250;

//color animation
const gradientAnimation = true;
var t = 0;
var speed = 0.1;

//division animation
var divideAnim = true;
var divide = true; //loop flag
var mod = 0.0; //color modificator

function drawTriangle(A, B, C)
{
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(A.x, A.y);
    context.lineTo(B.x, B.y);
    context.lineTo(C.x, C.y);
    context.lineTo(A.x, A.y);

    if(gradientAnimation)
    {
        context.fillStyle = 
        "rgb(" + 
            ((A.x + A.y) * 0.19 * mod) + "," + 
            ((B.x + B.y) * 0.15 * mod) + "," + 
            ((C.x + C.y) * 0.22 * mod) + 
        ")";
    }
    
    context.fill();
}

function fractal(center, halfSideLen, i)
{
    i++;
    var quaterSide = halfSideLen * 0.5;
    
    //calc new triangle coords
    var A = { 
        x: center.x - quaterSide, 
        y: center.y
    };
    
    var B = {
        x: center.x + quaterSide, 
        y: center.y
    };
    
    var C = {
        x: center.x, 
        y: center.y + halfSideLen   
    };
    
    drawTriangle(A, B, C);
    if(i < iterations)
    {       
        fractal({x: A.x, y: A.y + quaterSide}, quaterSide, i);
        fractal({x: B.x, y: B.y + quaterSide}, quaterSide, i);
        fractal({x: C.x, y: C.y - (halfSideLen + quaterSide)}, quaterSide, i);
    }
}

function update()
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    //init coords
    var A = { 
        x: center.x - halfTriangleSide, 
        y: center.y + halfTriangleSide
    };
    
    var B = {
        x: center.x + halfTriangleSide, 
        y: center.y + halfTriangleSide
    };
    
    var C = {
        x: center.x, 
        y: center.y - halfTriangleSide      
    };
    
    context.fillStyle = "#F00";
    drawTriangle(A, B, C);  
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    
    if(iterations != 0) fractal(center, halfTriangleSide, 0);   
    
    t += speed;
    if(t > Math.PI * 2)
    {           
        t = 0;
    
        if(divideAnim)
        {
            if(iterations == maxIterations) divide = false;
            else if(iterations == 0) divide = true;
            
            if(divide) iterations++;
            else iterations--;
        }
    }
    
    if(gradientAnimation)
    {
        mod = 1.25 - Math.sin(t) * 0.5;
    }
    
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Good things:

- `const` is used for variables that shouldn't be re-assigned
- `requestAnimationFrame()` is used for animating
- constants and global variables are declared at the top of the script.
- only three functions are used

### Suggestions

- add a space after control structures like `if` for readability: this is recommended in many style guides (e.g. [AirBnB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#whitespace--before-blocks), [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#formatting-whitespace))
  Instead of

  > ```
  > if(gradientAnimation)
  > ```

  Add a space:

  ```
  if (gradientAnimation)
  ```
- Also recommended by some popular style guides: avoid `var` unless a global variable is needed. Default to using `const` to avoid accidental re-assignment (which seems to be a topic of [this discussion on your other JS post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192477/circle-line-segment-collision#comment369930_192500)). If re-assignment is needed then use `let`.
- Use equality operators that don’t coerce types when not needed:

  Instead of:

  > ```
  > if(iterations == maxIterations)
  > ```

  Use `===`

  ```
   if (iterations === maxIterations)
  ```
- A common convention in many languages (including C-based and others) is to have constants that truly never change named using ALL_CAPS - e.g. `MAX_ITERATIONS` instead of `maxIterations`, `HALF_TRIANGLE_SIDE` instead of `halfTriangleSide`, etc.
- the lone `i++` at the start of `fractal()` can be moved down to conditional after the call to `drawTriangle()` and converted to a pre-increment:

  ```
      if (++i < iterations)
  ```
- Most of the (idiomatic) JS code and JS Style guides I have seen have opening braces on the same line as the function signature or control structure instead of a new line. Perhaps having them on a new line is common in another style guide (e.g. C++, C#, etc.).

Comment: In C# brackets starting blocks are always in a new line, maybe that's where it's coming from.

Comment: @potato- thanks for the insight - I have taken it into account as I updated that section